# Use cases with higher value on one variable for each case of another variable in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I am doing a meta-analysis in R. For each study (variable StudyID) I have multiple effect sizes. For some studies I have the same effect size multiple times depending on the level of acquaintance (variable Familiarity) between the subjects.

```
head(dat)
   studyID A.C.Extent Visibility Familiarity p_t_cov group.size same.sex  N published
1       1        3.0        5.0           1  0.0462          4        0  44         1
2       1        5.0        2.5           1  0.1335          4        0  44         1
3       1        2.5        3.0           1 -0.1239          4        0  44         1
4       1        2.5        3.5           1  0.2062          4        0  44         1
5       1        2.5        3.0           1 -0.0370          4        0  44         1
6       1        3.0        5.0           1 -0.3850          4        0  44         1
```

Those are the first rows of the data set. In total there are over 50 studies. Most studies look like study 1 with the same value in "Familiarity" for all effect sizes. In some studies, there are effect sizes with multiple levels of familiarity. For example study 36 as seen below.

```
head(dat)
      studyID A.C.Extent Visibility Familiarity p_t_cov group.size same.sex  N published
142      36        1.0        4.5           0  0.1233       5.00        0  311         1
143      36        3.5        3.0           0  0.0428       5.00        0  311         1
144      36        1.0        4.5           0  0.0986       5.00        0  311         1
145      36        1.0        4.5           1 -0.0520       5.00        0  311         1
146      36        1.5        2.5           1 -0.0258       5.00        0  311         1
147      36        3.5        3.0           1  0.1104       5.00        0  311         1
148      36        1.0        4.5           1  0.0282       5.00        0  311         1
149      36        1.0        4.5           2 -0.1724       5.00        0  311         1
150      36        3.5        3.0           2  0.2646       5.00        0  311         1
151      36        1.0        4.5           2 -0.1426       5.00        0  311         1
152      37        3.0        4.0           1  0.0118       5.35        0  123         0
153      37        1.0        4.5           1 -0.3205       5.35        0  123         0
154      37        2.5        3.0           1 -0.2356       5.35        0  123         0
155      37        3.0        2.0           1  0.1372       5.35        0  123         0
156      37        2.5        2.5           1 -0.1401       5.35        0  123         0
157      37        3.0        3.5           1 -0.3334       5.35        0  123         0
158      37        2.5        2.5           1  0.0317       5.35        0  123         0
159      37        1.0        3.0           1 -0.3025       5.35        0  123         0
160      37        1.0        3.5           1 -0.3248       5.35        0  123         0
```

Now I want for those studies that include multiple levels of familiarity, to take the rows with only one level of familiarity (two seperate versions: one with the lower, one with the higher familiarity).
I think that it can be possible with the package dplyr, but I have no real code so far.

In a second step I would like to give those rows unique studyIDs for each level of familiarity (so create out of study 36 three "different" studies).

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(studyID) %>%
  mutate(nDist = n_distinct(Familiarity) > 1) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(
    studyID = case_when(nDist ~ paste(studyID, Familiarity, sep = "_"), TRUE ~ studyID %>% as.character),
    nDist = NULL
  )
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 19 x 9
   studyID A.C.Extent Visibility Familiarity p_t_cov group.size same.sex     N published
   <chr>        <dbl>      <dbl>       <int>   <dbl>      <dbl>    <int> <int>     <int>
 1 36_0           1          4.5           0  0.123        5           0   311         1
 2 36_0           3.5        3             0  0.0428       5           0   311         1
 3 36_0           1          4.5           0  0.0986       5           0   311         1
 4 36_1           1          4.5           1 -0.052        5           0   311         1
 5 36_1           1.5        2.5           1 -0.0258       5           0   311         1
 6 36_1           3.5        3             1  0.110        5           0   311         1
 7 36_1           1          4.5           1  0.0282       5           0   311         1
 8 36_2           1          4.5           2 -0.172        5           0   311         1
 9 36_2           3.5        3             2  0.265        5           0   311         1
10 36_2           1          4.5           2 -0.143        5           0   311         1
11 37             3          4             1  0.0118       5.35        0   123         0
12 37             1          4.5           1 -0.320        5.35        0   123         0
13 37             2.5        3             1 -0.236        5.35        0   123         0
14 37             3          2             1  0.137        5.35        0   123         0
15 37             2.5        2.5           1 -0.140        5.35        0   123         0
16 37             3          3.5           1 -0.333        5.35        0   123         0
17 37             2.5        2.5           1  0.0317       5.35        0   123         0
18 37             1          3             1 -0.302        5.35        0   123         0
19 37             1          3.5           1 -0.325        5.35        0   123         0
```

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use dplyr, you could create an alternate ID or casenum by using `group_indices`:

```
df <- df %>%
  mutate(case_num = group_indices(.dots=c("studyID", "Familiarity")))
```